# Properly pass an element to React for Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to create and render a React element without using JSX:

```
function Weekday(props) {
    return React.createElement('p', null, `Today is ${props.day}`);
}

let dayElem = React.createElement(Weekday, {day: 'Monday'});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(dayElem);
```

This is based on a tutorial that I am following. As you can see, `createElement()` is being called twice above. I thought it was weird and decided to define `dayElem` like this:

```
let dayElem = Weekday({day: 'Monday'});
```

It still works and renders the content properly. Is there a particular reason why the tutorial did it the first way, instead of simply calling the function?

Are there any disadvantages of using the second method?

Thanks.

Comment: Once `Weekday` starts using hooks, that makes it a component and you must render it as an element. For now it's just an ordinary JavaScript helper function that could be called in other components.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi :). So this means the shorter method will only work as long as there are no hooks involved in `Weekday`?

Comment: Exactly. Also it will lead to a slightly different render tree in the react internals, which might affect performance (probably trading a little speed for a little memory)